# how can i put the integerValue for textField into the array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, for-loop

```
@property NSMutableArray*textFieldsA;

@property NSMutableArray*textFieldsB;

@property NSMutableArray*textFieldsR;

@property NSMutableArray *operandArrayA;

@property NSMutableArray *operandArrayB;

_textFieldsA = @[self.textFieldA0, self.textFieldA1, self.textFieldA2, self.textFieldA3, self.textFieldA4, self.textFieldA5, self.textFieldA6, self.textFieldA7, self.textFieldA8];
_textFieldsB = @[self.textFieldB0, self.textFieldB1, self.textFieldB2, self.textFieldB3, self.textFieldB4, self.textFieldB5, self.textFieldB6, self.textFieldB7, self.textFieldB8];
_textFieldsR = @[self.textFieldR0, self.textFieldR1, self.textFieldR2, self.textFieldR3, self.textFieldR4, self.textFieldR5, self.textFieldR6, self.textFieldR7, self.textFieldR8];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    _operandA = [((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text integerValue];
    _operandB = [((UITextField*)_textFieldsB[i]).text integerValue];
    [self.arithmetic setOperandA:_operandA operandB:_operandB operator:_operator];
    _finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.arithmetic result]];
    ((UITextField*)_textFieldsR[i]).text = _finalString;
}
```

how can i put the integerValue of

```
 self.textFieldA0.text , self.textFieldA1.text , self.textFieldA3.text ........self.textFieldA8.text
```

in to the array (operandArrayA)?

i have tried

```
 operandArrayA[i] = [((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text integerValue];
```

but it is not work, how should i do?

Comment: What is your error if it's not working ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can not add primitive datatypes in `NSArray`. You need to create object of `NSNumber` for integer value. Store this object to an array.

Like this:

```
NSNumber *number = @([((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text  integerValue]);
operandArrayA[i] = number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alloc and initialize all the arrays..like below

```
     operandArrayA=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     operandArrayB=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //if u want to store strings

    [operandArrayA  addObject:((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text];
    [operandArrayB addObject:((UITextField*)_textFieldsB[i]).text];

     //(OR) if u want to store integer value then u need to convert to NSNumber

     [operandArrayA  addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text integerValue]]];
    [operandArrayB addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[((UITextField*)_textFieldsB[i]).text integerValue]]];

   //(OR)

   operandArrayA[i]=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[((UITextField*)_textFieldsA[i]).text integerValue]];
   operandArrayB[i]=[NSNumber numberWithInt:[((UITextField*)_textFieldsB[i]).text integerValue]];
```

Hope it helps you..